# ROS MODBUS TCP DELTA PLC

Tags: ros, tcpros, plc

I am working on ROS modbus to communicate with PLC to read holding register of Delta AS228P PLC. I have installed the ros modbus device driver package

https://github.com/bitmeal/ros-modbus-device-driver/tree/master

and run the rosrun ros_modbus_device_driver modbus_device_driver.py _mapping:=devicemapping.json with mapping of json file.
It was executed without error. But when I run rostopic list, it doesn't show any active topic. Can anyone give me a solution for this issue.
I have modified json file.
Shall I specifiy the same name for coil, discrete input and holding register which was given in readme portion in github link?
Do you want me to create subscriber program to access the holding register?
In their paper, they have given different topic name for coil and register. In github, the author specified different one. Which one I would prefer to use.

My Delta PLC coil address is 00001
Holding register address is 40001

Below is the configured json file

// modbus-slave configuration example
{
"name": "mymodbusslave",

```
"address": "192.168.1.5",
"port": 502,
"unit": 0,
"timeout": 3,

"rate": 20,

"byteorder_reverse": false, // byte order: default, big endian
"wordorder_reverse": false, // word order: default, little endian

"discrete_read_continuous": true,
"discrete_read_separation_gap": 64,

"registers_read_continuous": false,

"mapping": {
    "coils": {
        "gripper": 1,
        "signal": 2,
        // ...
    },
    "discrete_inputs": {
        "overload": 10001,
        "presence": 10010,
        // ...
    },
    "input_registers": {
        "distance": {
            "address": 40001,
            "type": "WORD"
        },
        // ...
    },
    "holding_registers": {
        "name": {
            "address": 40000,
            "type": "WORD",
        },
        // ...
    }
}
```

}

[image: I got the below result]

Comment: The below code is for json configuration file